# What was the difference between CLOAD and LOAD "C:"?

Tags: atari, atari-basic

8-bit Atari Basic had three different formats of storing programs on tape.

- `CLOAD`/`CSAVE`
- `LOAD "C:"`/`SAVE "C:"`
- `ENTER "C:"`/`LIST "C:"`

I understand the specifics of the last one - it behaved as if the contents of the file were typed from keyboard; with some rather simple hack you could save something else than the program in memory; a common one was appending `RUN` at the end of saved program making it autorun upon loading, as the command was executed as soon as the program was loaded.

I understand `LOAD` could take other handlers, like `D:` for disk. I've long and fruitfully used it with `T:` for tape in Turbo mode provided by cartridge.

But I completely fail to see the point behind `CLOAD`. Did it provide anything `LOAD C:` didn't? The two save methods were incompatible, you couldn't perform `CLOAD` on what you saved with `SAVE C:` so it wasn't just syntactic sugar. What was its purpose and difference "behind the scenes"? Saving typing "C:" seems pointless?

Comment: [This page](http://www.atarimania.com/faq-atari-400-800-xl-xe-how-do-i-run-a-program-from-cassette_21.html) says that `CLOAD` is faster, but doesn't explain why. Probably it has something to do with how much processing is done to the data before it is saved/after it is loaded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The three commands correspond to three different storage formats.

- `CSAVE` drives the cassette recorder directly, and stores tokenized files using short inter-record gaps. This is the fastest mode (both when writing and reading) since it uses a compact representation and doesn't need to wait for the tape.
- `SAVE "C:"` uses the cassette tape driver, and stores tokenized files in the standard tape format with long inter-record gaps.
- `LIST "C:"` again uses the cassette tape driver, but it stores text files containing the BASIC listing in ATASCII. This is the slowest mode since it uses a verbose representation.

`LIST "C:"` provides the best compatibility, since any program which can read text files can load the listing. It also avoids the [Rev. B BASIC bug](http://www.atarimagazines.com/compute/issue61/323_1_INSIGHT_Atari.php) which causes programs to grow by 16 bytes every time they're loaded.

Comment: This begs the question though, why didn't the C: driver simply use smaller inter-record gaps for all LOAD/SAVE operations? Was there any need for a second format?

Comment: Can't speak for the original developers, but I found the long intra-record gaps gave more processing time to deal with incoming data. Not useful in the context of BASIC, but when doing other I/O.