# Obtaining a CPU execution trace on a Commodore 64

Tags: commodore-64, 6502, debugging

I need to collect the execution trace of all instructions executed by the 6502 on a C64. I tried C64 Debugger, but I couldn't find any option for this. Is it possible to obtain with C64 Debugger?  Are there any other tools for this?

Comment: What do you mean with by "all current instructions"? The instruction that the program counter is currently pointing at?

Comment: @Edders yes, instructions that cpu handled.

Comment: I would rather ask what is meant by ‘collect’.

Comment: @user3840170 Think of Wireshark

Comment: dntknw asked similar questions a couple of weeks ago (like this one: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/24194/home-computers-of-early-80s-capable-of-saving-basic-programs-as-machine-code)

Comment: Terminology: what you're asking for is generally known as an instruction trace.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you using an emulator? VICE has the `chis` (CPU history) monitor command for analysing instruction activity.

> `cpuhistory [<count>] [c:] [8:] [9:] [10:] [11:]` 
> `chis [<count>] [c:] [8:] [9:] [10:] [11:]`
>
> Show <count> last executed commands on up to
> five devices. If no devices are specified, then the default device is
> shown. VICE emulation runs each CPU for a variable number of cycles
> before switching between them. They will be synchronized when
> communication between them occurs. (disabled by default; configure
> with --enable-cpuhistory to enable)

— [VICE Manual, §12.2](https://vice-emu.sourceforge.io/vice_12.html#SEC289)

Comment: Sounds good, but Vice needs to be recompile??? But how?

Comment: The nightly builds have *--enable-cpuhistory* active. Grab one of those instead of / as well as the current RTM version. I keep two versions in my build toolchain - the RTM one for stable accuracy, and a nightly build purely for the *chis* feature so I can see what Commodore were smoking when they wrote some of the VIC-20 kernel.

Comment: I am very confused where to find it: https://vice.pokefinder.org/ says "This service is now cancelled and we are not planning on reviving it here.". I walked around files on SF, nothing found that seems to be nightly build. Where can I find it?

Comment: Hmm, the pokefinder site was where I used to go myself. Looks like no-one is doing regular nightly builds at the moment, so my suggestion would be to hit the official repo (**https://sourceforge.net/projects/vice-emu/files/**) and see if any development/experimental binaries have been compiled with *--enable-cpuhistory*.

Comment: Are you from c64 scene? Just wondering :)

Comment: I've been coding on Commodore 8-bit machines since 1980, so technically I'm from the PET/VIC/C64/C16/+4 scenes ;)